# Is there a way to create more flexible loops with Dataweave maps?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a problem that would take me ten seconds in any other language but here I am unable to solve it with Dataweave.

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "100": [{
        "courseID": "100",
        "course": "physics",
        "instructor": "John S",
        "section": "A",
        "date": "01-01-1900"
    }],
    "200": [{
        "courseID": "200",
        "course": "math",
        "instructor": "Jim R",
        "section": "A",
        "date": "01-03-1900"
    },
    {
        "courseID": "200",
        "course": "math",
        "instructor": "Jim R",
        "section": "B",
        "date": "01-07-1900"
    },
    {
        "courseID": "200",
        "course": "math",
        "instructor": "Jim R",
        "section": "C",
        "date": "01-08-1900"
    }

    ]}
}
```

I know for certain that the objects in the arrays contain duplicate information, except for section and date. So I need to condense it and transform it into this:

```
{
    "courses": [{
        "courseID": "100",
        "course": "physics",
        "instructor": "John S",
        "sections": [{
            "section": "A",
            "date": "01-01-1900"
        }]
    },
    {
        "courseID": "200",
        "course": "math",
        "instructor": "Jim R",
        "sections": [{
            "section": "A",
            "date": "01-03-1900"
        },
        {
            "section": "B",
            "date": "01-07-1900"
        },
        {
            "section": "C",
            "date": "01-08-1900"
        }]
]}
```

I can't get this to happen. I have tried every way I can see to iterate over the document, using map(), mapObject(), and pluck(). They need to be nested I would think, and I only want to pull ID, course, and instructor from the first course it iterates over, then continue to build out the object with the section data. The nesting seems to cause problems because there is a mix of objects and arrays, and map() and mapObject() complain if a nested function is returning the wrong type. This is the kind of thing I've been trying without success:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"courses": payload.pluck(courseValue, courseKey, courseIndex) -> 
               courseValue map (classValue, classKey, classIndex) ->
                   { courseID: classValue.courseID,
                     instructor: classValue.instructor
                     etc...
 }
```

I hope that's all clear. I'm pretty burnt out from messing with it for so long. Is it possible what I want to do is just too complex for DW to handle and I should use another method?

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work in all DataWeave versions

```
courses: (payload pluck $$) map using (c = payload[$]) {
  courseID : $,
  course: c[0].course,
  instructor: c[0].instructor,
  sections: c map {
    section: $.section,
    date: $.date
  }
}
```

This solution worked in Mule 3.x but not in 4.x, which is explained in this blog post under 'Automatic Coercion from Object to Array': https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/dataweave-mule-4-beta-syntax-changes-part-1/

```
courses: payload map {
  courseID: $[0].courseID,
  course: $[0].course,
  instructor: $[0].instructor,
  sections: $ map {
    section: $.section,
    date: $.date
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Unfortunately this does not work for me. I get the following error:

Message               : "You called the function 'map' with these arguments: 
  1: Object ({"100": [{courseID: "100",course: " physics",...)
  2: Function (($:Any, $$:Any) -> ???)

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: Array
  2: Function

I tried changing map() to mapObject(), which does not give me an error, but only outputs the last course from the input. It appears to loop over itself and overwrite the output on each iteration, resulting in only the last course in output.

Comment: The error message you have posted suggested you are using Mule 4.x, so after doing some research on the changes in Mule 4.x, I have added a solution that I expect will work for you

Comment: So this sort of works, but it will only output the last course in the list. Sort of like a loop overwriting its own output on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using DataWeave 2.0. Here is the simple DataWeave transformer that you can use.

**Transformer:**

```
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    courses: (payload pluck $$) map ((courseValue, courseKey) -> {
        courseID: payload[courseValue][0].courseID,
        course: payload[courseValue][0].course,
        instructor: payload[courseValue][0].instructor,
        sections: payload[courseValue] map ((sectionValue, sectionKey) -> {
            section: sectionValue.section,
            date: sectionValue.date
        }) 
    })  
}
]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
```

**Input:**

```
{
  "100": [
    {
      "courseID": "100",
      "course": "physics",
      "instructor": "John S",
      "section": "A",
      "date": "01-01-1900"
    }
  ],
  "200": [
    {
      "courseID": "200",
      "course": "math",
      "instructor": "Jim R",
      "section": "A",
      "date": "01-03-1900"
    },
    {
      "courseID": "200",
      "course": "math",
      "instructor": "Jim R",
      "section": "B",
      "date": "01-07-1900"
    },
    {
      "courseID": "200",
      "course": "math",
      "instructor": "Jim R",
      "section": "C",
      "date": "01-08-1900"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "courses": [
    {
      "courseID": "100",
      "course": "physics",
      "instructor": "John S",
      "sections": [
        {
          "section": "A",
          "date": "01-01-1900"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "courseID": "200",
      "course": "math",
      "instructor": "Jim R",
      "sections": [
        {
          "section": "A",
          "date": "01-03-1900"
        },
        {
          "section": "B",
          "date": "01-07-1900"
        },
        {
          "section": "C",
          "date": "01-08-1900"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```